# How to say 'No Pressure'

Tags: word-choice

How would you say 'No pressure' in a business context where you are trying to convey the lack of a need for urgency of completing a task?

Is it something like 別にする必要なく?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would often hear the following expressions:

「無理{むり}しなくてもいい（です）よ。」

「（特{とく}に）急{いそ}いでしなくてもいい（です）よ。」

「もしダメでも気{き}にしないで。」

「もしすぐにできなくても気にしないで。」

In one of the companies I have worked for, some people actually used:

「ノープレッシャーでいいですよ。」

beause almost everyone spoke English there.

Finally, 「別{べつ}にする必要{ひつよう}なく。」 is an incomplete sentence ending in the continuative form 「なく」 and it can be taken to mean "***You don't have to do it***.", which you probably would not want to be saying.

Comment: Can 気楽に be used instead?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to say that there ought to be more sense of urgency or awareness about the work in the environment?

> 「もっと気にかけた方が良いですね。」 (Maybe) it's better to be concerned (about it).
>
> 「こちらは気が利くべきですね。」 (You) should be more sensible/thoughtful/smart about this. ← 注意：English translation sounds stronger than is the Japanese.
>
> 「もっと注意しましょう。」 We should be more careful.

Comment: I think it's the opposite case: OP wants to tell someone that the case is not that urgent.